# nodejs throws offset out of bound error on file read using fstat

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Hi am using nodejs and scoket io for pushing some data to target. Am reading the json data from json file to push it to target.

Am using the fstat of fs module to read a file but whenever there is a concurren correction or after some time it throws offset out of bound error.

Here is the code snippet.

```
   fs.stat(fileName, function(error, stats) {
      fs.open(fileName, "r", function(error, fd2) {
         var buffer = new Buffer(stats.size);

          fs.read(fd2, buffer, 0, buffer.length, null, function(error, bytesRead, buffer) {
            var data = buffer.toString("utf8", 0, buffer.length);

           fs.close(fd2);
     })
    })
```

This is the error it is throwing

```
  fs.js:457
  binding.read(fd, buffer, offset, length, position, wrapper);
      ^
  Error: Offset is out of bounds
      at Object.fs.read (fs.js:457:11)
      at /var/custom_nodejs_projects/js/server.js:84:14
      at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

Can someone guide me here what could be the issue as struggling with this from past two days.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for not using a readable stream?

Comment: Concurrently writing and reading the same file is bound to cause errors at some point without some form of locking.

Comment: @rodrigo the reason am using the json file to read is its being updated by some other application and am reading from nodejs to push it to target using socket.io. If you provide some insight of how can i use the readable stream in this context it would be of great help

Comment: @robertklep if i do concurrent file read using fstat is the problem ?

Comment: @rodrigo i used the readstream as suggested by you but am getting EMOFILE error this is the code am using http://pastebin.com/06H0peHh  can you help in finding the issue here.

Comment: @SrinivasHN you're starting a file watcher on the _same_ file for _every_ connection. That's not scalable. Better start just one global file watcher and some event-based mechanism. You should probably create a new question on SO for this, though.

Comment: oh i got it now what you are saying .. do you have some inputs towards events for file watching is there any example as such . I am new to this nodejs so asking

Comment: @SrinivasHN you should really create a new SO question for this.

Comment: I created a new question but i have one doubt is fs.watchFile is not suggested over fs.watch ?

Answer (score 1):

If a file exists but is empty (0 bytes), calling `fs.read()` will fail with the error you're showing.

So before reading it, make sure `stats.size` isn't 0.

Comment: I will try this out and let you know

Comment: i tried what you have said but now am gettng the EMOFILE error . I tried using the readable stream also but am getting the same error. I have the code in the link http://pastebin.com/06H0peHh can you please help me in this what am doing wrong

Comment: @SrinivasHN `EMFILE` (I assume) is an error that you get when you have too many files open. It depends on the context in which you're running your file reading code. For one, you should _always_ close your file descriptors. I would suggest that you use `fs.readFile()` instead of `fs.open()/fs.read()`.

Comment: i am using fs.readFile and createReadStream am not using the fs.open() or fs.read(). Am really confused with the behaviour